# Globally configure length units in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{positioning}


\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  x = 1cm,
  y = 1cm,
  node distance = 2,
  auto,
  on grid,
  test/.style =
  {
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep = 0pt,
    semithick,
    minimum width = 0.5,
  },
  box/.style =
  {
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum width = 1,
    minimum height = 1,
    inner sep = 0pt,
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node (node1) at (0,0) [label=right:test, test] {};
\node (node2) [below=of node1, label=right:box, box] {};

\node (node3) [right=of node1, label=right:test, test, minimum width = 0.5cm] {};
\node (node4) [below=of node3, label=right:box, box, minimum width = 1cm, minimum height = 1cm] {};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

In the first two lines of the `tikzset` statement, I want to set the measurement units to be 1cm, so, according to my oppinion, the `test` node should be 0.5cm in width (and height, because it is a circle), and the `box` node should have a side length of 1cm each. However, if we look at the result of the above code

[image: wrong distances]

we can clearly see that
a) the nodes seem to be positioned correctly, the appear like there is a 2cm distance between them, as expected;
b) the size of the left two nodes is wrong - I would expect the left two nodes to have the same size as the right two ones, but this isn't the case.

How shall I change my `tikzset` code to have the correct sizes of the left two nodes? I don't want to use something like

```
test/.style =
{
  draw,
  circle,
  inner sep = 0pt,
  semithick,
  minimum width = 0.5cm,
},
```

because I want the node sizes be relative to the node distances and relative to each other. If I would use absolute widths and heights within the style definitions for the nodes, this would be rather unflexible, so I wonder whether it is possible to set the length of "1 unit".

Comment: yes I know. But I don't want to use units, as I said - instead I want relative lengths. I.e. the width shall be 1/2 of the node distance and so on.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can define a style `unit length` that sets a custom length `\unitlen` usable later in your drawings. I set the default length to `1cm` in the following code.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newlength\unitlen
\tikzset{
  unit length/.code={\setlength{\unitlen}{#1}},
  unit length = 1cm,
  node distance = 2,
  auto,
  on grid,
  test/.style =
  {
    draw,
    circle,
    inner sep = 0pt,
    semithick,
    minimum width = 0.5\unitlen,
  },
  box/.style =
  {
    draw,
    rectangle,
    minimum width = 1\unitlen,
    minimum height = 1\unitlen,
    inner sep = 0pt,
  },
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (node1) at (0,0) [label=right:test, test] {};
    \node (node2) [below=of node1, label=right:box, box] {};
    \begin{scope}[unit length=.5cm]
      \node (node3) [right=of node1, label=right:test, test] {};
      \node (node4) [below=of node3, label=right:box, box] {};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remarks :**

- The `x=1cm` and `y=1cm` are used only for coordinates without units, not for lengths.
- Another solution is to pass a parameter to your `box` and `test` that is a length, with default value of 1cm.

Comment: thanks. That works well. I would also like to set `x=\unitlen` and `y=\unitlen`, such that I can also use e.g. `\draw (0,0) -- (1,0)` to draw a line of unit length. However, it doesn't work if I use the `x=` and `y=` keys in the `tikzset` statement. Is it possible to make this work as well?

Comment: You can try `unit length/.append style={x=#1,y=#1}` may be.